# How fix the error: System.InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, .net

I have dropdown and when i upload the page i getting the error: System.InvalidOperationException: "The ViewData item that has the key 'id_Language' is of type 'System.String' but must be of type 'IEnumerable'."

This part of my code:

```
   <div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => Model.id_Language, Resource.Language)
     <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-6">
      @Html.DropDownList("id_Language", ViewBag.language as SelectList, new { @class = "form-control", @required = "required" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: It would really be helpful to see the code that generates the view data.

Comment: Yes, i alredy find answer. I was need just create the SelectList in Controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me solution was add an SelectList in controller and share ViewBag date in View

```
public ActionResult AddUser(){
   UserInfo u = new UserInfo(db);
            var languages = db.tbLanguage.Select(s => new SelectListItem()
            {
                Text = s.Language,
                Value = s.idLanguage.ToString()
            }).ToList();

ViewBag.language = languages;
return View();
}
```

And in view:

```
<div class="form-group">
    Html.LabelFor(m => Model.id_Language, Resource.Language)
       <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-6">
         @Html.DropDownListFor(m=> m.id_Language, ViewBag.language as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, "", new { @class = "form-control", @required = "required" })
       </div>
</div>
```